# No follow/no index link for product filter forms on ecommerce website

Tags: javascript, html, google-crawlers

For an ecommerce store we have a filter possibility on the collection page. This is done through a get form. If for example: product A is available in white or black. The following link will open dynamically once the “white color checkbox” gets clicked on the filter form:

*URL: store.com/collectionpage/?filter%5B%5D=472109*

The problem is that search engines now crawl those crazy links and costs crawlingbudget. What’s the best way to no-index or no-follow these links?

Things to keep in mind:

- It’s not a link where I can add:  meta name="robots"
  content="noindex, nofollow"
- I don't have access to robots.txt